# python Find the longest substring without any number and at least one upper case character

Tags: python-2.7

I've been stuck trying to figure out how to find the longest substring with no numbers and at least one uppercase. Especially when it comes to at least one upper case. I tried iterating over the string and appending the element to a new list. Then if the element came to a number, I tried to see if any of the elements in a new list had a capital letter. Any help will be appricated. Thank you

Comment: sounds like a job for regular expressions. And instead of describing what you've tried, perhaps you could show the code you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: If you have code - please show that. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm Overview:

> Iterate over the string, if we see a number then add the substring before that number to a dictionary, where the key is the length of the substring and the value is the substring. Return the max-length substring.

The code for this is as follows:

```
def longestSubstring(s):
    max_length = 0
    tmp_length = 0
    tmp_uppercase_count = 0
    tmp_string = ""
    strings = {}
    nums = '0123456789'
    s_length = len(s)
    for i in range(s_length):
        if s[i] not in nums:
            if s[i].upper() == s[i]:
                tmp_uppercase_count += 1
            tmp_length += 1
            tmp_string += s[i]
            if tmp_uppercase_count > 0 and i == s_length - 1:
                strings[tmp_length] = tmp_string
                max_length = max(max_length, tmp_length)
        else:
            if tmp_uppercase_count > 0:
                strings[tmp_length] = tmp_string
                max_length = max(max_length, tmp_length)
            tmp_length = 0
            if i != s_length - 1:
                tmp_string = ""
                tmp_uppercase_count = 0
    if len(strings) == 0 and tmp_uppercase_count > 0:
        return tmp_string
    elif len(strings) == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        return strings[max_length]
```

Note that instead of going for shorter code, I looked more for time complexity. This code runs in O(N) time.